# Unmountable_Boot_Volume 0x000000ED

Tags: windows-xp, window

TECHINICAL INFORMATION 0x000000ED (0x823304E0,0xC0000006, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)
I have windows xp and it was working fine until the next day What do I do?

Comment: -1: Your question does not show research effort.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy one.  You need to run chkdsk /f c:
Boot from your Windows XP CD and select "recovery mode"
You will eventually get to a DOS like prompt

Type:
**chkdsk /f c:**

wait for it to complete and you will be fine.

Alternatively, you can use Windows 7 or 8 bootable DVD or USB and select "repair computer"
then "Command Prompt"
then type:
**chkdsk /f c:**